# Soap web servive access in iphone iOS

Tags: objective-c, web-services, soap, iphone

I need help for access web service in iOS (for below web service code). i try to implement soap web service to access web service but it returns false result. I give username and password directly and try to access, but its required base64 encrypted  string for access this service (for example user name will be give in type of encrypted like  NSString *Username=@"username:password"; ). This Username can convert to base64 encryption and then to access the web service.
        I don't know how set header for AuthHeader and credentials tags for accessing below web service. so any one help me how to immplement bellow web service on iPhone.

```
SOAP 1.1
The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.
POST /Test_Express/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: external.test.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/LoginValidation"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <credentials>string</credentials>
    </AuthHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <LoginValidation xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
    </LoginValidation>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <LoginValidationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <LoginValidationResult>string</LoginValidationResult>
    </LoginValidationResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
SOAP 1.2
The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.
POST /Test_Express/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: external.test.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <credentials>string</credentials>
    </AuthHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <LoginValidation xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
    </LoginValidation>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <LoginValidationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <LoginValidationResult>string</LoginValidationResult>
    </LoginValidationResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP GET
The following is a sample HTTP GET request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.
GET /Test_Express/Service.asmx/LoginValidation?username=string&password=string HTTP/1.1
Host: external.test.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">string</string>
HTTP POST
The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.
POST /Test_Express/Service.asmx/LoginValidation HTTP/1.1
Host: external.test.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

username=string&password=string
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">string</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you start by going here: [SOAP iOS generator](http://sudzc.com/) this will allow you to communicate with your SOAP Web Service in a clean simple way.

Comment: I already try this, but its return false (output : {"bIsSuccessful":false,"sMessage":Value cannot be null. Parameter name: InString}) but expected o/p :{"bIsSuccessful":true,"sMessage":Value cannot be null. Parameter name: InString}

Comment: Please verify, if base64encode username is correct or not. Have you tried to hardcode the soap string format in request format.

Comment: I call web service using java, give username name like "username:password" and then call base64 encode method to encrypt string and then set header for credentials to access web service successfully. Same way i try in iOS , but i didn't know to call web service through encrypted string.